# High memory consumption in unlist of list-of-lists of POSIXct

Tags: r, xts, nested-lists, posixct

I have around 500-2000 lists of POSIXct dates in a list of lists looking like this:

```
ts <- lapply(c(1:500), function(x) seq(as.POSIXct("2000/1/1"), as.POSIXct("2017/1/1"), "hours"))
```

I need a list of unique dates. I have tried several things:

```
t <- unique(do.call("c", ts))
```

This preserves the POSIXct class, but takes very long and uses 7-8GB of memory; even though he whole list of lists is like 500MB or so.

```
t <- as.POSIXct(unique(unlist(ts, use.names = FALSE)), origin = "1970-01-01")
```

This goes much faster, though the memory consumed is roughly the same. So I tried to split it with this:

```
t <- lapply(split(ts, ceiling(seq_along(ts)/30)), function(x) {
  return(unique(unlist(x, use.names = FALSE)))
})
t <- unique(unlist(x, use.names = FALSE))
```

Same consumption and it seems to me like the memory comes from the `unlist()` or `unique()` call on just one of "small" lists.

Is there a way to achieve this memory efficient? Processing time matters, but just a little. If the list size doubles (which is likely) this may cause serious problems.

Comment: What is `do.apply()`?

Comment: It's was called do.call. Edited.

Comment: You could, also, try `Reduce(function(x, y) unique(c(x, y)), ts)` to handle your large "list" in pairs accumulating the result

Comment: @alexis_laz: you should post that as an answer. If you use the method in my answer, you'll see that it only uses ~200MB. I had thought of it too, but don't want it to look like I swiped your answer.

Comment: This seems to work and seems to drain just a third of the memory though it takes longer. Seems pretty good. What actually is the cause for do.call taking that much more?

Comment: Manually handling list-of-lists is pretty painful, recommend you use `tidyr` tibbles or `data.table`, both can handle multi-indexes and are way more performant, and can near-instantly compute unique keys.

Comment: Also, a fallback is storing your datetimes as integer-seconds-since-epoch e.g. `as.integer(as.POSIXct("2000/01/01")) = 946713600` which is only 48 bytes. 10x more compact even than POSIXct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a large vector with `do.call(c, .)`/`unlist(.)` and a single large hash table which have a high memory usage as shown in Joshua's answer, we could follow the less time-efficient but more memory-efficient way of processing "ts" iteratively:

```
ff1 = function(x)  ## a simple version of `Reduce(unique(c()), )`
{
    ans = NULL
    for(elt in x) ans = unique(c(ans, elt))
    return(.POSIXct(ans))
}
system.time({ ans1 = ff1(ts) })
#   user  system elapsed 
#  11.41    1.25   12.74
```

"ts" has identical elements. Though this ideal is not generally the case, we could try to avoid some concatenations if possible:

```
ff2 = function(x)
{
    ans = NULL
    for(elt in x) {
        new = !(elt %in% ans)
        if(any(new)) ans = c(ans, elt[new])
    }
    return(.POSIXct(ans))
}
system.time({ ans2 = ff2(ts) })
#   user  system elapsed 
#   6.65    1.12    7.93
```

On the same note, `fastmatch` package has a very interesting but, unfortunately, not exported, high level hash table functionality that we could try using here. It should, also, be more light on memory consumption.

First define some convenient wrappers:

```
HASH = function(x, size) fastmatch:::mk.hash(x = x, size = size)
APPEND = function(x, what) fastmatch:::append.hash(hash = x, x = what, index = FALSE)
HTABLE = function(x) fastmatch:::levels.fasthash(x)
```

And build the same concept on it:

```
ff3 = function(x, size)
{
    h = HASH(double(), size)
    for(elt in x) h = APPEND(h, elt)
    return(.POSIXct(HTABLE(h)))
}
system.time({ ans3 = ff3(ts, sum(lengths(ts)) / 1e2) }) #an estimate of unique values
#   user  system elapsed 
#   4.81    0.00    4.87
system.time({ ans3b = ff3(ts, length(ts[[1]])) }) #we know the number of uniques
#   user  system elapsed 
#   2.03    0.03    2.10
```

And to compare:

```
all.equal(ans1, ans2)
#[1] TRUE
all.equal(ans2, ans3)
#[1] TRUE
```

On a smaller example to illustrate:

```
set.seed(1821)
tmp = split(sample(1e2, 26, TRUE) + 0, rep(1:4, c(6, 3, 11, 6)))

identical(unique(unlist(tmp)), as.double(ff1(tmp)))
#[1] TRUE
identical(unique(unlist(tmp)), as.double(ff2(tmp)))
#[1] TRUE
identical(unique(unlist(tmp)), as.double(ff3(tmp, 1e2)))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: went with the iterative Reduce for now. But will definitely look into fastmatch.

Comment: This is just manually computing unique keys/values, which is something `data.table` or `tidyr` tibbles will do for free. Manually managing huge lists-of-lists is a code smell that the OP needs a more powerful data structure than can handle multi-indexes, quickly compute unique keys etc.

Answer (score 2):

The `unique(do.call("c", ts))` call uses < 4GB (3869.9 - 606 ~ 3GB) of RAM on my machine. And the `ts` object is 568MB.

```
R> ts <- lapply(c(1:500), function(x) seq(as.POSIXct("2000/1/1"), as.POSIXct("2017/1/1"), "hours"))
R> gc()
           used  (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb) max used (Mb)
Ncells   221687  11.9     460000  24.6   392929   21
Vcells 74925836 571.7  112760349 860.3 79427802  606
R> t <- unique(do.call("c", ts))
R> gc()
           used  (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb)  max used   (Mb)
Ncells   221729  11.9     460000   24.6    392929   21.0
Vcells 75074953 572.8  413082177 3151.6 507227169 3869.9
R> print(object.size(ts), units="MB")
568.8 Mb
R> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Setting `recursive = FALSE` and `use.names = FALSE` makes it faster and drops the memory consumption to ~2GB.

```
R> ts <- lapply(1:500, function(x) seq(as.POSIXct("2000-01-01"), as.POSIXct("2017-01-01"), "hours"))
R> gc()
           used  (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb) max used  (Mb)
Ncells   221686  11.9     460000  24.6   371201  19.9
Vcells 74925836 571.7  111681359 852.1 80924280 617.5
R> u <- do.call("c", c(ts, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE))
R> gc()
            used   (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb)  max used   (Mb)
Ncells    221725   11.9     460000   24.6    371201   19.9
Vcells 149446409 1140.2  413082872 3151.6 373009943 2845.9
```

Using `unlist` with the same arguments is a little lighter on memory consumption:

```
R> ts <- lapply(1:500, function(x) seq(as.POSIXct("2000-01-01"), as.POSIXct("2017-01-01"), "hours"))
R> gc()
           used  (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb) max used  (Mb)
Ncells   221686  11.9     460000  24.6   371201  19.9
Vcells 74925836 571.7  111681359 852.1 80924280 617.5
R> u <- .POSIXct(unlist(ts, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE))
R> gc()
            used   (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb)  max used   (Mb)
Ncells    221695   11.9     460000   24.6    371201   19.9
Vcells 149446337 1140.2  358453576 2734.8 298487368 2277.3
```

---

Adding [alexis_laz's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42929535/high-memory-consumption-in-unlist#comment72957298_42929535), you can see that memory consumption is a measly 230MB:

```
R> ts <- lapply(c(1:500), function(x) seq(as.POSIXct("2000/1/1"), as.POSIXct("2017/1/1"), "hours"))
R> gc()
           used  (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb) max used  (Mb)
Ncells   218429  11.7     460000  24.6   389555  20.9
Vcells 74922694 571.7  111432506 850.2 81226910 619.8
R> u <- Reduce(function(x, y) unique(c(x, y)), ts)
R> gc()
           used  (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb)  max used  (Mb)
Ncells   218893  11.7     460000  24.6    389555  20.9
Vcells 75072416 572.8  111432506 850.2 111399894 850.0
```

Comment: Actually good method to use the gc() in a fresh console.. Tried my stuff in R-Studio and the results are wierd so I watched my top. Thanks for the documenation.

Comment: Using `top` may be hard to gauge how much memory R is actually using, because it reports what the OS has allocated to the process, not necessarily what the process has requested and/or is using.